# Waiting onSuccess to return JSON

Tags: android, httprequest

I have a class with function for get some JSON files like that in my Cards.class :

```
public class Cards {
    static JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    public static JSONObject getCards(Context context)
    {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.addHeader("x-access-token", Preferences.getToken(context));
        client.get("http://api.app.com/users/" + Preferences.getID(context), null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                Log.d("debugIID", "Cards success : " + statusCode);

                String json = new String(bytes);

                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("debug", "Cards JSONObject : " + jsonObj);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("debug", "Cards failure : " + statusCode);
            }
        });

        return(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

This is how I call this function to get the JSON in my MainActivity.class :

```
final JSONObject json = Cards.getCards(getApplicationContext());
Log.d("DebudIID", "Cards JSON : " + json);
```

The problem is the json Object is null in the MainActivity.
In the getCards function, the json is good un the onSuccess.

It seem, the function get the return before waiting the onSuccess.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of async is that you can't do that – your function returns before the success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callback interface to get your data back to your caller. Consider the example below:

```
public interface CardsResponse {
   onResponseReceived(JSONObject response);
}
```

Then your `getCards` will looks like this:

```
    public static void getCards(Context context, CardsResponse cardsResponse)
    {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.addHeader("x-access-token", Preferences.getToken(context));
        client.get("http://api.app.com/users/" + Preferences.getID(context), null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                Log.d("debugIID", "Cards success : " + statusCode);

                String json = new String(bytes);

                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    cardsResponse.onResponseReceived(jsonResponse); // This line will return to your caller

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("debug", "Cards JSONObject : " + jsonObj);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("debug", "Cards failure : " + statusCode);
            }
        });
    }
```

And finally the caller:

```
final JSONObject json = Cards.getCards(getApplicationContext(), new CardsResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(JSONObject response) {
                // Do stuff here
                Log.d("DebudIID", "Cards JSON : " + json);
            }
        });
```